# $.each not rendering JSON in given Order

Tags: jquery

Here is my JSON from server

```
"bids":{"51200512":{"bidAmt":"Rs.63,736,494.00","date":"2014 12 12 09:49:59 AM","bidder":"Amit"},

"69120512":{"bidAmt":"Rs.734,294.00","date":"2014 12 12 09:51:29 AM","bidder":"Tata India Pvt Ltd"},

"66560256":{"bidAmt":"Rs.87,265.00","date":"2014 12 12 09:52:31 AM","bidder":"Tata Telecommunication servoices &lt;i&gt;asas&lt;/i&gt; Telec"},

"69120768":{"bidAmt":"Rs.63,737.00","date":"2014 12 12 09:52:05 AM","bidder":"Tata India Pvt Ltd"},

"69120256":{"bidAmt":"Rs.63,736.00","date":"2014 12 12 09:50:50 AM","bidder":"Tata India Pvt Ltd"}}}
```

In fire fox its shows the correct order i.e.

```
Rs.63,736,494.00
Rs.734,294.00
Rs.87,265.00
Rs.63,737.00
Rs.63,736.00
```

but in chrome:

```
Rs.63,736,494.00
Rs.734,294.00
Rs.63,736.00
Rs.734,294.00
Rs.63,737.00
```

Here is how i am parsing my JSON

```
 $.each(bids,function(k,v){
       _tbl+="<tr bd='y'><td><a href=\""+_this.options.context+"/profile/"+k+"\">"+v.bidder+"</a><br/><small><span class='timeago' title='"+v.date+"'>"+v.date+"</span><small></td><td>"+v.bidAmt+"</td></tr>";
 });}

$("#showBidModel table").append(_tbl);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886494/jquery-sort-results-of-each

Comment: no you see the output both are rendering all data but not in same order as in the json list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript does not guarantee the order of objects. See [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Chrome happens to iterate through them with the numeric keys first in sorted order. If you need explicit ordering, use an array.

```
"bids": [
    {"id": "69120512", "bidAmt":"Rs.734,294.00","date":"2014 12 12 09:51:29 AM","bidder":"Tata India Pvt Ltd"},
    {"id": "66560256", "bidAmt":"Rs.87,265.00","date":"2014 12 12 09:52:31 AM","bidder":"Tata Telecommunication servoices &lt;i&gt;asas&lt;/i&gt; Telec"},
    ...
]
```