# Iterate through array of json objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have array of json object as following

```
{
    "01/15/2015_1": [
        [
            {
                "sequenceType": -1,
                "delflag": -1
            },
            {
                "sequenceType": -1,
                "delflag": -1
            }
        ]
    ],
    "01/15/2015_2": [
        [
            {
                "sequenceType": -1,
                "delflag": -1
            },
            {
                "sequenceType": -1,
                "delflag": -1
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

By iterating it with jquery's each() I am getting object as following order:

```
1."01/15/2015_1"
2."01/15/2015_2"
```

But I want it in reverse() say as following:

```
1."01/15/2015_2"
2."01/15/2015_1"
```

Need help..

Is it possible with ng-repeat?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Sort results of $.each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886494/jquery-sort-results-of-each)

Comment: Actually you are iterating properties of the object, not array. ECMAscript does not actually define order for the properties. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An Objekt has no defined order, so you cannot make sure this works well in every browser.

You have to grab the keys, `Object.keys()`, sort them and loop through it by key.

e.g.:

```
var obj = {
    "01/15/2015_1": [
       "example1"
    ],
    "01/15/2015_3": [
        "example3"
    ],
    "01/15/2015_2": [
        "example2"
    ]
}
var keys = Object.keys( obj ).sort();
var klen = keys.length;
for( var idx = 0; idx < klen; idx++ ){
    console.log( obj[ keys[ idx ] ] )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906061/can-i-make-jquerys-each-method-iterate-in-reverse:

Sulution:

```
$.each(array.reverse(), function() { ... });
```