# How to display the data base values order by date using jquery here?

Tags: jquery, sql, database

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
      $(document).ready(function()
               {
                        $("#datetbtn").click(function(){
                     db.transaction(function(tx) {
                     tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM materials_table ORDER BY time;',[], querySuccess);
                         });    
                                                });
                                                });
     </script> 


function updateMaterialDB(tx) {
                time = new Date();
query = 'INSERT INTO materials_table (id, material_title, type, course_id,last_accessed,) VALUES (' 

                + time + '", "'
                + size + '", "'
                + is_downloaded
                + '")';
                query = query.replace(/\//g,"");
                console.log(query);
                tx.executeSql(query);
            }
```

Here i  want to display the values order by date using jquery ? here the values are not changed in the line using query

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM materials_table ORDER BY time;',[], querySuccess);
                         });
```

Comment: What datatype is `time`? Have you tried running this script in SSMS? Does it produce different results?

Comment: time = new Date();
time is a variable

Comment: do not write down your sql code into javascript , it can be hacked very easily. do it by ajax call with a backend code..

Comment: ok ok. here after i wont .how to call the ajax

Answer (score 0):

Take the data in json format and in json format you can sorting data.

Reference : [Sorting a JavaScript object by property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359761/sorting-a-json-object-in-javascript)