# sort json by jquery key value

Tags: jquery, json, sorting, key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359761/sorting-a-javascript-object)

I have a json data like this

```
[
  {
    "name":"anand",
    "type":"0"
  },
  {
    "name":"bajaj",
    "type":"0"
  },
  {
    "name":"cat",
    "type":"1"
  }
]
```

I populate these data in a table with header,  name and type.

I have stored these data in a javascript global array. Now i have to sort that global array 
according to key.

For example when i click the name it has to sort according to name and same for type.

I have tried many things but it is giving sort is not a function error.

```
var data_obj= [];  // declared a global variable 

 $.ajax({url: url,
         type:"post",
         data: "folder="+folder,
         success: function(data){
             data_obj = data // here i store returned json data in a global variable 
         }  
 });
```

a simple sort function

```
 data_obj.sort(function(a, b){
     return [a.name] < [b.name] ? -1 : 1;
 });
```

But it is giving me sort is not a function. Please help me in sorting according to key.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359761/sorting-a-javascript-object

Comment: Why are you wrapping the two names in arrays and then comparing the arrays?

Comment: See the dupe. It's your exact question and, nope, it cannot be done.

Comment: Solution: [JQuery: Sorting JSON by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/jquery-sorting-json-by-properties/14949429#14949429)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the server is sending the JSON back with the wrong Content-Type (it is common for people writing PHP to forget to override the default HTML content type with `header('Content-Type: application/json');`).

This would result in `data` being an HTML DOM instead of an Array inflated from JSON, so it wouldn't have a `sort` method.

Comment: I have inserted type as   contentType: 'application/json', in ajax call still it is giving same error

Comment: @user1403248 — The `contentType` property is documented such *When sending data to the server, use this content type*. It doesn't make any difference to the response (unless the server reacts to getting a JSON *request* by 500ing or otherwise not giving you the data you want at all). It is the HTTP Content-Type header in the **response** you need to change.