# Array of Array to an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array like

```
var myArray = [
  [ '12345678912312', '982322' ],
  [ '98789213123123', '443434' ],
  [ '34534565465645', '387423' ],
  [ '67898798799299', '345334' ],
  [ '09324242342342', '234232' ],
];
```

which I want to convert into an Array of object, something like:

```
var myObject = [
  {
    id: '12345678912312',
    num: '982322',
    hour: new Date.getHours(),
  },
  {
    id: '98789213123123',
    num: '443434',
    hour: new Date.getHours(),
  },
  {
    id: '34534565465645',
    num: '387423',
    hour: new Date.getHours(),
  },
  {
    id: '67898798799299',
    num: '345334',
    hour: new Date.getHours(),
  },
  {
    id: '09324242342342',
    num: '234232',
    hour: new Date.getHours(),
  },
];
```

I am using Underscore currently and wondering how (and if) I can use `_.object` and/or `_.map` to achieve something like this.

I will also like it to be return-able thing.
Like:

```
var newVar = _.object(_.map(myArray), function(k, v) {
  // Do something
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: You just need to map. `return {id:x[0],num:x[1],hour:new Date.getHours()}`. What you got is a collection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359761/sorting-a-javascript-object

Comment: I don't think `_.object` needs a predicate. as you are trying to give.

Answer (score 6):

If I understood what you want, This can be done with simple javascript native `map`

```
var myObj = myArray.map(function(el){
            return {id:el[0],num:el[1],hour:new Date().getHours()}
            });
```