# sort array objects [object Objects] in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

i have an array of objects. example [object Object]. This array is basically first object is the code of U.S and the second object is its fullname.

```
{AK: "Alaska", AL: "Alabama", AR: "Arkansas", AZ: "Arizona", CA: "California", CO: "Colorado"},
```

does anyone know how to sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Objects are not arrays, and can't be sorted.

Comment: any suggestions on how it can be done taking different approach?

Comment: What is your real task?

Comment: The question as it stands is not very clear. Can you describe exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Refer this solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1129270/2231822

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery - They use a list but the idea is transferable.

Comment: @CarlitosOverflow You can put all your object keys in another array, and then sort that array. After that you can access object by array keys.

Comment: @CarlitosOverflow After that you can access object by array keys. You don't need to sort object every time, just sort that array once and use anytime in your code.

Comment: This is either a duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value) or [Sorting a JavaScript object by property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359761/sorting-a-javascript-object), depending on whether you want to order by name or value.