# Sort objects in object by date React

Tags: javascript, object

How I can sort my object after add one value

```
{
2017-12-18:{210: {…}},
2017-12-20:{211: {…}},
2017-12-21:{186: {…}, 188: {…}, 189: {…}, 190: {…}, 201: {…}}
}
```

And now I add  object `2017-12-19:{220: {…}},` but how I can add this after date `2017-12-18` ?

Comment: I don't think order matters inside a JSON. Why do you need them sorted?

Comment: I add something in React and I have to show this in view but msut be after date 2017-12-18

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: I dont have any idea, all time think

Comment: Maybe you want to make a sorted array from your object? `[{ date: '2017...' , payload: {210:...}}, ...]`

Comment: Insert the keys in any order and then do: `Object.keys(json).map(function(d){ return new Date(d) }).sort()`. This will give you the keys (as Date object) but sorted. I hope you can make some progress with this.

Comment: Ok I try this .

Comment: You can remove tag `reactjs` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work

```
let sortedData = function sortObjectKeys(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce((acc,key)=>{
        acc[key]=obj[key];
        return acc;
    },{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer for [sort object by property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359761/sorting-a-javascript-object-by-property-name)

You can just run that function after adding a new "line" to your object.

I would advise you to make sure you are not overwriting and existing property in your object before you attempt to add a new one.