# Order response JSON from Ajax request

Tags: javascript

after an ajax request the original order is not preserved, I need to order this json by value:

```
{1: "c", 2: "a", 3: "b"}
```

Comment: This is pretty much just a request for us to write code for you, which is not what SO is for. Please do some research, try some things, and come back when you have a problem with the code that you write.

Comment: why not use an array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359761/sorting-a-javascript-object-by-property-name

Comment: Objects are not *ordered*, use an array instead.

Comment: I have a problem with 'the original order is not preserved'... HTTP is all text, if you send "Hello Mendy" you will never get anything else than "Hello Mendy". It's not like one day you have a chance to get "Hedy Menllo"

Comment: object `{}` properties don't have order, only array object `[]` values do