# JSON counts to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file and I want to use javascript/jQuery to count its contents and list the results.

Here's the initial code:

```js
var globalJsonVar;
$.getJSON("index.json", function(json) {
  globalJsonVar = json;

  /* Having fetched the json, search and index type:keyword */
  var types = {};
  json.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!types[item.keyword]) {
      types[item.keyword] = 0;
    }
    types[item.keyword]++;
    $('#menu').text(JSON.stringify(types));
  });
});
```

- Q1: How do I pass it to html?
- Q2: Can I split the "keyword" field to an array and count what's inside it as discrete entries? [This](https://api.myjson.com/bins/lz839) is the JSON file.

**Update** Q1 is already fixed here: https://jsfiddle.net/5089L59x/4/

Comment: [Once again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520583/counting-json-ocurrences-with-a-library#comment84036252_48520583) your question is very unclear. Please read and understand [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `I want each key and value in the same li and the value to be inside a span so I can style it.` is that not the target?

Comment: I tried to add the fiddle into the question but the fiddle has different code to that in the question so I don't know which one is relevant.

Comment: i guess the code is different to make it running on `jsfiddle`, but yea this is confusing

Comment: Thanks for your corrections @liam. I'm trying to boil down the problem to the simplest question, but I'm still not there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for Q1:** 
Basically all you have to do is to use the (for .. in .. ) loop to use all properties of an object. (the types object in this case)

```
var JsonVar;
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ba5at", function(jsonData) {
  var types = {};
  jsonData.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!types[item.keyword]) {
      types[item.keyword] = 0;
    }
    types[item.keyword]++;
  });

  for (var typeKey in types) {
    var newLiElement = document.createElement("li");
    var valueSpanElement = document.createElement("span");
    var valueTextNode = document.createTextNode(typeKey.toString());
    var keyTextNode = document.createTextNode("keyword: ");
    var countSpanElement = document.createElement("span");
    var countSpanText = document.createTextNode(types[typeKey].toString());

    //here you can style the keys
    valueSpanElement.setAttribute("style", "background-color: blue; color: white;");
    countSpanElement.setAttribute("style", "margin-left: 10px; background-color: black; color: white; text-weight: bold;");

    countSpanElement.appendChild(countSpanText);

    valueSpanElement.appendChild(valueTextNode);

    newLiElement.appendChild(keyTextNode);
    newLiElement.appendChild(valueSpanElement);
    newLiElement.appendChild(countSpanElement);


    document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(newLiElement);
  }
});
```

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/k8xn0n5v/5/

**Answer for Q2:** 
All you have to do is to create an array from the string keywords using the string.split() method. (in this case, the ', ' argument will work fine)

I have updated the fiddle, now you can find the keyword:count values in an array.

https://jsfiddle.net/5089L59x/15/

Extending the code of your fiddle looks like this:

```
var JsonVar;
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/lz839", function(jsonData) {
  var types = {};
  jsonData.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!types[item.keyword]) {
      types[item.keyword] = 0;
    }
    types[item.keyword]++;
  });

  var keywordsCountObject = {};
  for (var typeKey in types) {
    var keywordItemsToCount = typeKey.toString().split(", ");

    keywordItemsToCount.forEach(function(itemToCount) {
      console.log(itemToCount);
      if (!keywordsCountObject.hasOwnProperty(itemToCount)) {
        keywordsCountObject[itemToCount] = 1;
      } else {
        keywordsCountObject[itemToCount]++;
      }
    });
  }

  for (var prop in keywordsCountObject) {
    $("ul#menu").append("<li>" + prop + " " + keywordsCountObject[prop].toString() + "</li>");
  }

});
```

Comment: This works like a charm. My problem was getting the for loop right. I replaced everything in the brackets for `$("#menu ul").append("<li>" + typeKey.toString() + types[typeKey].toString() + "</li>")` — it's easier if I use jQuery.

Comment: I just noticed your edit and I think I get the principle of using `split()` but it doesn't work in the fiddle. Still a list of counted _strings_, not the discrete entries within the strings. Perhaps the split needs to come first, then the count?

Comment: Okay, wait a few mins, i take a look. :)

Comment: Okay, so you can find the extracted keywords in the keywordArray variable. Check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5089L59x/8/
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think so. The output I'm seeking would be like `Bubbles: 3, Computers: 3, Dogs: 3, Yellow: 1` (etc).

Comment: Oh. Okay, wait a few mins im on it.

Comment: I updated the Q2 section of my answer. Check it out!

Comment: That is perfect and I'm marking the question as solved! Thank you so so much. I'm only adding one more thing, but it's outside the scope of what I asked before: is there a way to sort the result alphabetically?

Comment: Thanks :) Happy to help you. I think here you can find answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359761/sorting-a-javascript-object-by-property-name

Comment: That was a precious clue and I ended up finding a jQuery answer for that, sorting the DOM elements and not the JSON itself — see here https://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/Cfpdu and a working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/psw1p5p2/2/

Answer (score 1):

you are searching for `for...in` loop:

```
var keyValues = [];

json.forEach(function(item){
if(!types[item.keyword]){types[item.keyword] = 0;}
    types[item.keyword]++
})
for (var attr in types) {
    console.log(attr)
    console.log(types[attr])
    $('#menu ul').append("<li>"+types[attr]+" <span>"+attr+"</span></li>")
    keyValues.push({key: types[attr], value: [attr]})
  }
console.log(keyValues)
```

html:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>

  </ul>
</div>
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k8xn0n5v/6/

further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

greetings

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly for the second part of the question, or for a string, but I also want to split it, so I can count and list the full scope of keywords.

Comment: will modify it, just wait a moment

Comment: [Que another long and tedious exchange in comments..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520583/counting-json-ocurrences-with-a-library#comment84037049_48520583) if you get your question right first then it makes everyone's life easier moving forward @east1999

Comment: is this what you are searching for @east1999 ?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. If you look at the output from your fiddle, it has more lines than the JSON file, so it's actually repeating them for some reason.

Comment: I forked your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mkkoo2gj/ adding a new field to the JSON, which has only one value per key, and the output still doesn't seem right.

Comment: sorry, i updated my fiddle. it was my bad, my loop was wrongly placed :/ check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/k8xn0n5v/6/

Comment: Yes, thank you @messerbill! It works very much like the fiddle I added in the post update. Two remaining qs: how to split the string so I can count _each_ keyword, and how to sort the result alphabetically

Comment: have a look here maybe u can get it from there on: https://jsfiddle.net/k8xn0n5v/7/ - i will return home now, once arrived i will have a look at this post. Have no more time right now ;)

Comment: Like I said in the comment to Belian's answer, it doesn't work in the fiddle. It's still the same list of counted strings.

Comment: so i really dont get what you ant to achieve, sorry

Comment: Let me just clarify: this code allows for counting the number of "keyword" strings. What I want is to split the string to an array, and count the values inside, i.e., a list with X Balloons, X Dogs, etc. Again, thank you for you contribution and your patience.

Comment: ok i can do this, but you already marked Beilan's answer solving the issue - so is your problem fixed yet or not?