# sort array of object based on data inside array

Tags: javascript

let say I have array like following

```
[
    {
        id:"1",
        name: "satu",
        data: [
            {
                id: "1.a",
                last_update: "07:00:00",
                value: 12
            },
            {
                id: "1.b",
                last_update: "08:00:00",
                value: 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id:"2",
        name: "dua",
        data: [
            {
                id: "2.a",
                last_update: "12:00:00",
                value: 1
            },
            {
                id: "2.a",
                last_update: "06:00:00",
                value: 5
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id:"3",
        name: "tiga",
        data: [
            {
                id: "3.a",
                last_update: "09:00:00",
                value: 17
            },
            {
                id: "3.b",
                last_update: "10:00:00",
                value: 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

how can I sort this array based on `last_update` prop inside `data` array? I expected `id=2` will be the first element of the sorted array, follow by `id=3`. the final result should be like following

```
[
    {
        id:"2",
        name: "dua",
        data: [
            {
                id: "2.a",
                last_update: "12:00:00",
                value: 1
            },
            {
                id: "2.a",
                last_update: "06:00:00",
                value: 5
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id:"3",
        name: "tiga",
        data: [
            {
                id: "3.a",
                last_update: "09:00:00",
                value: 17
            },
            {
                id: "3.b",
                last_update: "10:00:00",
                value: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id:"1",
        name: "satu",
        data: [
            {
                id: "1.a",
                last_update: "07:00:00",
                value: 12
            },
            {
                id: "1.b",
                last_update: "08:00:00",
                value: 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359761/sorting-a-javascript-object-by-property-name

Comment: @AmiraliAmirifar i don't think so. please read my post once again.

Comment: @Vukky nope, I can easily sort the data if it's only 1 dimensional array of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, here is working solution.

first of sort the `data` array inside each object

```
data.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b.last_update) - Date.parse(a.last_update))
```

then sort the main array

```
main.sort(a, b) => Date.parse(b.data[0].last_update) - Date.parse(b.data[0].last_update));
```

suppose every object has its `data` atleast 1 element.

in my actual code I am checking if the `data` array has atleast 1 element inside of it to prevent error undefined index 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.sort` with your own sorting function

Here's a quick example

```
let objs = [
    {
        id:"1",
        name: "satu",
        data: [
            {
                id: "1.a",
                last_update: "07:00:00",
                value: 12
            },
            {
                id: "1.b",
                last_update: "08:00:00",
                value: 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id:"2",
        name: "dua",
        data: [
            {
                id: "2.a",
                last_update: "12:00:00",
                value: 1
            },
            {
                id: "2.a",
                last_update: "06:00:00",
                value: 5
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id:"3",
        name: "tiga",
        data: [
            {
                id: "3.a",
                last_update: "09:00:00",
                value: 17
            },
            {
                id: "3.b",
                last_update: "10:00:00",
                value: 2
            }
        ]
    }
]

function compare( a, b ) {
  if ( a.data[0].last_update < b.data[0].last_update ){
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a.data[0].last_update > b.data[0].last_update ){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

objs.sort( compare );
```

Looking at your comment, maybe you want to add more conditions?

Comment: thanks for your effort, I solved it myself. thanks a lot.